# react-native-dmgapp-webview slow loading

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, webview, native

im using react-native-dmgapp-webview-android on my react native application.
In my home screen, the user clicks a URL and the webview takes a long time (>10 sec) to load it. It tries to completely load everything in the page before displaying
Is there a way to make it partially load the URL or pre-load/cache it?
Note: I know the initial URL in advance.

Also, I have a similar issue in iOS using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wkwebview-reborn.
Help on either would be much appreciated.

Comment: I find Webview very slow also.  Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: So do I.. @yoni rabin how was it?

Comment: Yes, I used chromium eventually, it took care of all loading/prefetching out of the box